# How to find the latest dropped node in ExtJs4 tree

Tags: drag-and-drop, tree, extjs4

I'm trying to implement the following:

I have 2 tree panels with enabled drag and drop. I can drag some items from the first tree to the second. The first tree is a catalog of components, the second is a product constructor. In some cases when I drop a node to the constructor, I need to append child to the dropped node. So actually when I drop I need to add 2 nodes at the same time: the node that was dropped and the second one I'm adding in code.

I decided to add that extra node in a drop event handler, but the problem is that I don't understand how find the latest dropped node.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to implement what I needed using a combination of two events `itemadd` and `drop`

Here is a sample, hope it will be helpful for somebody:

```
    onComponentAdd: function (records) {
        var record = records[0];
        this.lastAddedRecord = record;
    },

    onComponentDrop: function (element, data, dropNode) {
        var record = this.lastAddedRecord;

        var data = record.get('Data');
        if (!Ext.isEmpty(data)) {
            var scheme = data.scheme;
            Ext.each(scheme, function (item) {
                if (item.type == 'componentlist') {
                    record.appendChild({
                        text: item.name,
                        loaded: true,
                        expanded: true,
                        allowDrop: true
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `drop` event available with `Ext.tree.plugin.TreeViewDragDrop` class. This class basically provides drag or drop functionality for the tree's view (TreeView). So, you need to add the drop event to your TreeView object and add your child nodes or other operations when this event is triggered.

To configure the TreeView, you can use the `viewConfig` parameter available with tree panel class. Over the head, you might have
to code something like this:

```
viewConfig: {
    plugins: {ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop'},
    listeners: {
        drop: function(node,data,model,dropPosition,opts) {
            // Add child nodes & other modification codes here...
        }   
    }
}
```

Refer the [drop method in docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.tree.plugin.TreeViewDragDrop-event-drop) for more details on how to get the data you need.

Comment: yes, I know that I should use this plugin, but the problem is how to find that latest dropped node. I read the docs through, but I didn't find the answer, could you suggest anything?